# Why does IE apply my tinymce config only after pressing F5

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce-4

I'm maintaining an application that shows a rich text editor (Tiny MCE) in a popup window. Suddenly, the textarea has stopped from being converted to a rich text editor when the popup is shown. Only when I press F5, my tiny mce configuration is applied.

When I run the web application locally from within Visual Studio, all is fine.

There's no https involved in the deployed application.

I face the issue in IE 10 as well as IE 11, but not in Firefox 39.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading, I figured it might have something to do with the location of the `<script>` tag. It was in the `<head>` of the page, but since there's no jQuery involved, I'm not using `document.ready`. I moved the `<script>` tag to just below the `<textarea>` and now it seems to be working.

But: I'm not sure if this is really the solution because with the `<script>` tag in the `<head>`, it does work locally.

Some feedback would be much appreciated.